# You will need to set up login with Facebook to access the API

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, dart, facebook-audience-network

I've recently seen on **Facebook/Meta** audience network dashboard the following alert on the top.

> You will need to set up login with Facebook to access the API
>
> Starting in July 2022, you will need to use Facebook Login for your
> apps to access the Audience Network Reporting API, so you will no
> longer be able to generate a token to access the API. Signing in with
> Facebook is more secure and convenient, and protects against
> unauthorized ID sharing.

I don't understand exactly what i means. I'm using Facebook bidding with Applovin, that alert means that in July all my apps that don't have Facebook login will stop Audience network so will not show ads. It is a bit strange that i have to implement obligatorily Facebook Login if is not necessary. Can anyone explain me?

I appreciate.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what it is trying to say is not that in every app where you have Meta ads you compulsorily have to put Facebook login. It is a change in how we as developers will access the API.

Before we used to generate a API token and use it for authentication. Now in place of that we have a Facebook account login to authenticate and then we can use the API.

These is done to prevent the auth token sharing and also as they say its more secure and convenient then the traditional token way for using API.

You can check out the new documentation of how to use Facebook login for API authentication. Hope it helps.

Comment: in short, does this affect apps that don't have facebook login but are using FAN ?

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: Thank u, i understand now! I appreciate that u had explained it.

Comment: A dev in need is a dev indeed! No problem keep at the good work, and help others when you can. Happy coding